WildCard Certificate appears to be installed but not installed in reality
I am new to Powershell. But I put up this script by getting info from multiple SO threads and google search. I am trying to install wildcard certs on multiple servers in one go using below script.
$username = 'myusername'
$password = 'mypassword'

Write-Output "Starting Cert-Install as on $env:username. But $username will be used under the hood.."
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword

$sourceCertFile="wildcard_my_org.pfx"
$certPlaintextPassword='certpwd'

 
# Function to copy cert to remote servers and install them
function importCert {
    param(
        #[string[]]$computerNames=$env:computername,
        [string]$sourceCertFile,
        [string]$certPlaintextPassword
    )
    $certFileName=Split-Path $sourceCertFile -leaf
    $certFolder=Split-Path $sourceCertFile
    $targetLocalCertPath='C:\CertsPS\'+$certFileName
    $results=@() 
     if([System.IO.File]::Exists('serverlist.txt')) {
    try{  
        
        foreach($computerName in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines("serverlist.txt")){
        #foreach ($computerName in $computerNames){            
            $destinationDirectory="\\$computerName`\c`$\CertsPS"
            $destinationFile="$destinationDirectory\$certFileName"
            $copySuccess=if(!(test-path $destinationFile)){
                #$command="robocopy $certFolder $destinationDirectory $certFileName"
                write-host "Copying certs to $destinationFile"
                if(!(test-path $(split-path $destinationFile -Parent))){
                    $null=new-item $(split-path $destinationFile -Parent) -ItemType Directory
                }
                Copy-Item $sourceCertFile -Destination $destinationFile -Force -EA Stop       
            }else{$true}
            $psSession=new-pssession $computername -SessionOption $(New-PSSessionOption -OpenTimeOut 10000)  -Credential $credential
            if($copySuccess -and $psSession){                
                $result=Invoke-Command -session $psSession -ScriptBlock {
                    param($targetLocalCertPath,$certPlaintextPassword)
                    Write-Output "Importing cert on $env:computername. Currently logged in as $env:username"
                    try{
                        
                        $certEncryptedPassword=ConvertTo-SecureString $certPlaintextPassword -AsPlainText -Force
                        $newCert = Import-PfxCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -FilePath $targetLocalCertPath -Password $certEncryptedPassword

                       Import-Module Webadministration

                        $sites = Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:\Sites

                        foreach ($site in $sites)
                        {
                            foreach ($binding in $site.Bindings.Collection)
                            {
                                if ($binding.protocol -eq 'https')
                                {
                                    $search = "Cert:\LocalMachine\My\$($binding.certificateHash)"
                                    $certs = Get-ChildItem -path $search -Recurse
                                    $hostname = hostname
                
                                    if (($certs.count -gt 0) -and 
                                        ($certs[0].Subject.StartsWith("CN=*.mycomp.org")))
                                    {
                                        echo "Updating $hostname, site: `"$($site.name)`", binding: `"$($binding.bindingInformation)`", current cert: `"$($certs[0].Subject)`", Expiry Date: `"$($certs[0].NotAfter)`""

                                        $binding.AddSslCertificate($newCert.Thumbprint, "my")
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                       
                        return $true
                    }catch{
                        write-warning $_
                        return $false
                    }
                } -ArgumentList $targetLocalCertPath,$certPlaintextPassword -EA Stop
                $results+=$result
                remove-pssession $psSession
            }
        }

    }catch{
        write-warning $_
        continue
    }
   } else {
        Write-Output "File serverlist.txt does not exist ! "
        Write-Output "Make sure serverlist.txt exists at the same dir level as this script ! "
  }
    return $results

}

importCert $sourceCertFile $certPlaintextPassword

The output I get is following:
Starting Cert-Install as on adminuser1. But adminuser1 will be used under the hood..
Importing cert on server01. Currently logged in as adminuser1
Updating server01, site: "Default Web Site", binding: "*:443:", current cert: "CN=*.mycomp.org, O=ORG, S=New York, C=US", Expiry Date: "04/22/2024 19:59:59"
True
Importing cert on server10. Currently logged in as adminuser1
Updating server10, site: "Default Web Site", binding: "*:443:", current cert: "CN=*.mycomp.org, O=ORG, S=New York, C=US", Expiry Date: "04/22/2024 19:59:59"
True
Importing cert on server02. Currently logged in as adminuser1
Updating server02, site: "Default Web Site", binding: "*:443:", current cert: "CN=*.mycomp.org, O=ORG, S=New York, C=US", Expiry Date: "04/22/2024 19:59:59"
True

Although all seems working fine but to my horror, there is no cert installed at all. Only previously installed certs are there which are about to expire in few weeks. Another issue is no error is thrown and not sure how to debug on what I am missing. Any pointers/help will be greatly appreciated.

Where do you want certificate installed?  The user or machine?  You can check the registry to see under which keys the certificate is stored.  Do a search by certificate name.

I am reading the servernames from serverlist.txt file. And iterating the same to install certs on those servers. I searched for the certs but no where to be found.

This seems to be incorrect $destinationDirectory="\\$computerName\\c`$\CertsPS" the first escape is not needed. Try $destinationDirectory="\$computerName\c`$\CertsPS"`

@DougMaurer, while it's true that \ doesn't need escaping in string literals in PowerShell, inside "..." it also does no harm: "`\" -eq '\' is $true. Conversely, a $ meant to be used literally inside "..." doesn't strictly need escaping unless followed by a legal variable-name character: "$\" -eq '$\' is $true (though it's good practice to escape, "`$\".
